# Multiple search datatable Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to know if it was possible to search for 2 differents things and then redraw the datatable.

I'm now using this :

```
 var table = $('#something').DataTable();
    table
        .search(something1)
        .draw();
```

It is possible to do something like

```
table
.search(something1 || something2)
.draw
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) says that it only accepts a string, but you can use regex.

```
.search(/something1|something2/, true)
```

You can use [variables in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression).

Comment: Do I have to import something if I want to use regex? If not it seems to not be working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by using regex.

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable(); 
var temp = 'something1|something2';
        table.search(temp, true, false).draw()
```